# Find and replace multiple times in txt file

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I know this might have been asked before, but I could not find an answer to it.

I need to replace the following: CoverLevel="XX"   with CoverLevel="0" , this includes XX being any number, without replacing the similar instances such as CoverLevel="True" or  CoverLevel or MinCoverLevel="1.3"

would that be possible with notepad++ ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the bottom of the search/replace window you can select the search mode "regular expression", then you can search for

```
CoverLevel="\d\d"
```

the `\d` means any number, in a regular expression. This searches for two numbers, if you want to search for "one or more numbers" you can use the `+` quantifier `"\d+"`

Comment: Just curious, does this also conform with the last part of the question? `without replacing ... or MinCoverLevel="1.3"`

Comment: @TomHart Yes it does. `.` is not a digit.

Comment: Ahh yeah, I didn't think about that!

Comment: He can type it as '\bCoverLevel=\d+' the \b means word boundary so it starts with CoverLevel and is not part of the string. Also don't forget that you have to replace with CoverLevel + new expression.

Comment: And if XX was supposed to be limited to two digits (i.e. you don't want to replace CoverLevel="212", then you can use `CoverLevel="\d\d?"`, where `?` matches 0 or 1 instances.

Answer (score 1):

If you also want to leave something like `SomeOtherCoverLevel="1234"` untouched, you will need to use the following instead.

`^CoverLevel="\d+"$`

What you need is to delimit the begin and end to be sure nothing else is touched.